# TAILWIND | How to rewrite custom tailwind class

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to rewrite my .title class elements if needed.

```
.title {
    @apply text-[60px] leading-[64px] font-black text-white;
}

<div class='title text-red-300'> <==== how can I change text color to be red and not white?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it inside the `components` layer. [DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aVu7pSRmKw)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .title {
    @apply text-[60px] leading-[64px] font-black text-white;
  }
}
```